# Removing the beep sound when moving between elements in a folder

Tags: sound, keyboard

When we move between elements in a folder by means of the keyboard arrows and if we press it too many times to go beyond the existing number of elements, the system makes beeps for each time it cannot go any further within the directory. How to turn off this beeping sound?

Answer (score 0):

you can put into your ~/.inputrc file following line:

```
set bell-style none
```

this will turn off bell sounds.